# Buffer Overflow not happened

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I tried this sample c code:

```
int main()
{
    int array[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 10;
    }
}
```

and compile it using:

```
gcc -m32 -o a.out buffer2.c
```

**my question is why there is not Segmentation fault?**

i use kali linux 64

vendor_id : GenuineIntel

model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz

Architecture: x86_64

CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit

Byte Order: Little Endian

---

I edited code by adding these two lines:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 12;

    int array[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 10;
    }

    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

and that is the result:

```
10
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You've introduced undefined behavior, which means what happens is not well-defined. You absolutely *could* get a segmentation fault, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: undefined behavior is, well, undefined -- so it isn't *defined* to be a segfault, though often it is. (By the way -- a buffer overflow most certainly happened, it just didn't trigger a segfault)

Comment: A buffer overflow isn't the same as a segmentation fault.  You can buffer overflow and still access memory in your process' address space (which is a *serious* security problem).

Comment: You didn't get a segmentation fault because you didn't do anything that depended on the memory that you overwrote.

Comment: @Barmar yes it works now

Comment: 10^1000 dups of this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the uncountable dups of this question.

Comment: @MartinJames There are probably hundreds of duplicates to this question, but it's not off topic.

Comment: Hossam, consider yourself lucky for not getting a segfault in that code.

Comment: @Mike I'd consider it unlucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no runtime bounds checking in C. Writing to elements outside the bounds of an array is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Undefined behavior means that anything can happen as far as the standard is concerned. So, although a segmentation fault is fairly likely, it's by no means guaranteed.

Just because there wasn't a segmentation fault doesn't mean there wasn't a buffer overflow. There definitely was. It just didn't result in a segmentation fault this time. This type of error is serious and can cause a number of security problems. The moral of the story is don't cause a buffer overflow, ever. It's not safe, and you can't rely on C to protect you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

And compile again like this:

```
gcc buffer2.c -o buffer2 -fno-stack-protector
```

Comment: @LightFlow Undefined behavior is undefined, and although this might help cause a seg fault, it's still not guaranteed. Also, I strongly recommend you do *not* turn off randomized address space. That's a very useful security feature, and there are very few reasons you would turn that off.